# Show unshortened day of the week @ OSX menu bar

Tags: macos

Currently clock menu bar item shortens day of the week like Sat instead of Saturday. Is there any way to change this without additional software?

(tried regional formats but it ignores any custom changes for some reason, OSX 10.8.2)

Comment: FYI, [iStatMenus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) does this.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your [Date & Time Settings](http://www.extensions.in.th/amitiae/08_2012_2/language.html)

```
System Preferences > Date & Time > Open Language and Text... > Region > Dates > Customize...
```

Your current date is set to medium, change it to "Long" or "Full"

Comment: Are you sure? No date format on my system uses short day names, but it appears shortened in the menu bar. Also, *Date & Time* preference pane allows some customization (e.g. 12/24 hour clock – no format in my locale uses a 12 hour clock –, whether to show day of week, etc.), so it appears unrelated to the various default date/time formats.

Comment: That setting seems to only affect the date/time that it shows in the popup after you click on the menu item, not the menu item itself.